# Sql: One material code, having a particular vendor code, having multiple rates

Tags: sql

I need to have a count of the Material codes having multiple rates for a particular Vendor code

[The example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9G3r.png)

I need the Requiredoutput to be

```
11005433        1000323        15

11005433        1000323        0
```

Comment: pls. tag the DBMS (MySQL, MS SQL, Orcle, etc) which you are using.

Comment: your required output is very unclear, pls. edit your question & add some explanation for output.

Comment: Please edit your question to add [**sample data**](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. Provide them as [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and strictly [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **DO NOT** post code or additional information in comments. Please ensure you have a [**minimal, complete and verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: your required output is very simple by select * from tablename where Material = '11005433' and [Vendor code] = '1000323'

Comment: this will return your required output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Material VARCHAR(10),  [Vendor code]   VARCHAR(10),  rates INT)

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES 
('11005432','1000321',15),
('11005433','1000323',15),
('11005433','1000323',0),
('11005433','1000324',25)

;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Material,   [Vendor code] ORDER BY Material)  FROM @T
)
SELECT T.* FROM CTE
INNER JOIN @T T ON CTE.Material = T.Material AND CTE.[Vendor code] = T.[Vendor code]
WHERE CTE.RN> 1
```

Result:

```
Material   Vendor code rates
---------- ----------- -----------
11005433   1000323     15
11005433   1000323     0
```

Comment: And also, i have other fields, approx 80 fields to be extracted. How do i do that for the results?
Can i know how to run this code, in that manner?

Comment: Are you asking, how do you change temp table with your existing one?

Comment: Could you add your full table definition to the question?

Comment: there are 83 fields in my table. I need to extract all the fields, that have the same material, same vendor code, having multiple rates. My table name is Sheet1. I have already imported this file into SQL. Can you please give me the query accordingly? Thanks!

Comment: Change '@T1' table with Sheet1 and add all additional colums to 'PARTITION BY' and 'INNER JOIN' conditions

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. Could you mark the answer as correct?